# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее: тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее (и почему):

Но такой подход ведет лишь к пребыванию во мраке неведения, опираясь на него, крайне трудно достичь понимания и переживания глубокого смысла в своем опыте.

**Или:** 
Но такой подход ведет лишь к пребыванию во мраке неведения – опираясь на него, крайне трудно достичь понимания и переживания глубокого смысла в своем опыте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Но такой подход ведет лишь к пребыванию во мраке неведения – опираясь на него, крайне трудно достичь понимания и переживания глубокого смысла в своем опыте.*

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), отношения между частями БСП **причинно-следственные**, и это желательно обозначить с помощью двоеточия или тире, то есть более сильными знаками, чем запятая.

Тире является **более универсальным и удобным знаком**, в устной речи тире соответствует паузе.

**Примечание.** Двоеточие обычно ставится в том случае, если нужно точно указать, что причина на втором месте. Но чаще всего в этом нет особой необходимости, поэтому двоеточие заменяется тире.